# Changing a hover function from image swap to opacity change

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a site that I change the background of the site when you hover over links.  It works fine, but I would rather load all of the images and then change the opacity to make the current one visible, it seems like it will make the transitions smoother.

Here is the html

```
<div id="bg">
<img src="images/bg.jpg" alt="">
</div>



<div class="mainnav">
<img src="images/hsna-logo.png" class="logo">
<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="#" class="hoverbg" data-bgsrc="images/bg1.jpg">LINK1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="hoverbg" data-bgsrc="images/bg2.jpg">LINK2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="hoverbg" data-bgsrc="images/bg3.jpg">LINK3</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="hoverbg" data-bgsrc="images/bg4.jpg">LINK4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here is the css;

```
#bg {
position: fixed; 
top: -50%; 
left: -50%;
width: 200%; 
height: 200%;
}
#bg img {
position: absolute; 
top: 0; 
left: 0; 
right: 0; 
bottom: 0; 
margin: auto; 
min-width: 50%;
min-height: 50%;
}
```

This is the jquery function that swaps the images;

```
$(function(){
$('.hoverbg').hover(
  function(){
    var newimg = $(this).data("bgsrc");
    $('#bg img').fadeOut('slow',function(){
        $(this).attr('src', newimg);
        $(this).fadeIn('slow');
    });
},
function(){
    $('#bg img').fadeOut('slow',function(){
        $(this).attr('src', 'images/bg.jpg');
        $(this).fadeIn('slow');
});
});
    });
```

I would like to set the div with all of the possible images just with the opacity of the main background image set to 1;

```
 <div id="bg">
 <img src="images/bg.jpg" alt="" opacity="1">
 <img src="images/bg2.jpg" alt="" opacity="0">
 <img src="images/bg3.jpg" alt="" opacity="0">
 </div>
```

Then use jquery to animate the opacity changing from the previous background image to whatever the new one is, then have it default to the original when a user moves out of the hover.  Any suggestions, I am unsure how to tell it to take the newimg variable and adjust the opacity of that image to 1, and the original image to 0.

Comment: be aware that while `$(this).data('attr')` will read `data-attr`, but when writing, it will use a memory instance of the element last time I checked.  `$(this).attr('data-attr')` is generally safer imo.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this to get you on the right track:

```
 <div id="bg">
     <img src="images/bg.jpg" alt="" class='image active'>
     <img src="images/bg2.jpg" alt="" class='image inactive'>
     <img src="images/bg3.jpg" alt="" class='image inactive'>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
#bg{
    position:relative;
    width: /* Set the width */;
    height: /* Set the height */;
}

.active{
    opacity: 1;
}

.inactive{
    opacity: 0;
}

.image{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Script

```
$('.image').hover(function(){
    $('.image').animate({
        opacity : 0
    }, 500);
    $(this).animate({
        opacity : 1
    }, 1000);
});
```

**EDIT BASED ON COMMENT:**

Try this

```
$('.hoverbg').hover(function(){
    $('#bg img').animate({
        opacity : 0
    }, 500);

    $('#bg img').attr('src', $(this).attr('data-bgsrc'));

    $('#bg img').animate({
        opacity : 1
    }, 1000);
});
```

Here is the code I am trying to use, it works fine until I change it to use the newimg variable.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.hoverbg').hover(
    function(){
      var newimg = $(this).attr('data-bgsrc');
      $('#bg img [src="'+ newimg +'"]').animate({opacity:1},1000);
      $('#bg img [src!="'+ newimg +'"]').animate({opacity:0},500);
    })
    });
```

Comment: This is much more elegant, but it works for the user hover on the image, not on a link in a different div.  My mainnav div has the image source I am currently passing to the script to load the different image, any thoughts on how to pass that across to to update the correct image?

Comment: I've added an edit above. Check it out and see if that works for you.

Comment: It is closer, I was just trying something like that, but I can't seem to get the class to update based on the data-bgsrc.  It now just sets all of the background images to 0 opacity on hover, then stays there on out.

Comment: I feel like i am much closer now, if anyone can give me another push i think i will have it.  I added the code I am now using.  It just doesn't seem to be passing the variable.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I worked with a previous answer and ended up changing to the mouseover and mouseout functions.  This does exactly what I want it to. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.hoverbg').mouseover(
function(){
   var newimg = $(this).attr('data-bgsrc');
   $('#bg img[src!="'+newimg+'"]').attr('class', 'inactive');
   $('#bg img[src="'+newimg+'"]').attr('class', 'active');
});
$('.mainnav ul').mouseout
(function(){
   $('#bg img[src="images/bg.jpg"').attr('class', 'active');
   $('#bg img[src!="images/bg.jpg"]').attr('class', 'inactive');
});
});
```